# Allowing only a specific `typedef` as a function argument

Tags: c++, typedef

Is it possible to allow only a specific `typedef` as a function argument?

```
typedef int foo;
typedef int goo;

void f(goo g); //I don't want to accept anything `foo` as an argument
```

If not possible simply with `typedef`, what language construct can I use to achieve this effect?

Comment: use `struct goo {.....};` instead, and don't define any converting constructors

Comment: How would you pass a `foo` anyway? Is `f(1)` OK? The actual argument will be an expression, not an identifier.

Comment: alternatively use `enum class goo { .... };`

Answer (score 5):

No, they are not different types, only different names for the same type.

If you want them to be different types, you can define them as structs:

```
struct foo
{
    explicit foo(int v) : value(v) {}
    int value;
};

struct goo
{
    explicit goo(int v) : value(v) {}
    int value;
};

void f(goo g);

// ...

foo a(23);
goo b(34);
f(b); // good
f(a); // bad
f(goo(45)); // good
f(foo(56)); // bad
```

Or you could templateify:

```
template<typename T, typename tag>
struct newtype
{
    explicit newtype(const T& v) : value(v) {}
    T value;
};

struct foo_d {};
struct goo_d {};
typedef newtype<int, foo_d> foo;
typedef newtype<int, goo_d> goo;
```

Answer (score 0):

An argument has a type, the function allows any argument of the type declared which is int in your case, try classes/structs instead